# Obtener valor máximo según fecha

Tags: php, sql, subconsultas

BASE DE DATOS
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/38PrfMVrWrHXJUDGq3bdxm/18

Necesito filtrar la columna saldo de acuerdo a la fecha seleccionada, tengo un archivo php en donde solo hay dos input, en ellos pones una fecha de inicio y una fecha final, en la consulta que coloque, puse esa fecha como ejemplo pero ahi va dependiendo de lo que ingresen, por ejemplo si coloco como fecha maxima 2021-11-22 23:59:59 tendría que ser el resultado 183 pero si yo colocara en los input la fecha 2021-12-02 23:59:59 tendría que aparecer 149 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT m.codigo,m.nombre_material,uni.unidad,
(SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='ENTRADA') AS entradas,
(SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='SALIDA') AS salidas,
(SELECT mo.saldo FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo AND (identrada = (SELECT MAX(identrada) FROM movimientos)) ) AS saldo,
m.cantidad,mo.fecha from material as m 
inner join unidad_medida uni on  uni.idunidad_medida =  m.unidad 
inner join movimientos mo on mo.codigo_material= m.codigo 
where mo.fecha BETWEEN '2013-02-09 00:00:00' AND '2021-11-22 00:00:00'  
GROUP BY `m`.`codigo`  ASC
```

Comment: Creo que esa consulta debe generar error porque no hay un `ORDER BY`, pero sí un `ASC`.

Comment: no me genera ningun error. me da todos los datos correcto menos la consulta (SELECT mo.saldo FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo AND (identrada = (SELECT MAX(identrada) FROM movimientos)) ) AS saldo, me devuelve siempre el ultimo valor pero no me filtra por fecha

Comment: El saldo proviene de una subconsulta, que también debería tener el filtro de fecha.

Comment: (SELECT mo.saldo FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo AND (identrada = (SELECT MAX(identrada) FROM movimientos WHERe mo.fecha BETWEEN '2013-02-09 00:00:00' AND '2021-11-22 00:00:00' )) ) AS saldo.

Comment: Creo que no dará el resultado esperado. De cualquier forma, prueba primero en PHPMyAdmin y nos comentas cómo te fue.

Comment: muchas gracias bro, ahi coloque la respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Se tiene que agregar también la fecha a la subconsulta que se esta realizando con la columna saldo y agregar otra subconsulta de la columna cantidad y dejarlo fuera del filtro de fecha para que ese sea fijo

```
SELECT m.codigo,m.nombre_material,uni.unidad,
(SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='ENTRADA') AS entradas,
(SELECT SUM(mo.cantidad) FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo and mo.tipo_movimiento='SALIDA') AS salidas,
(SELECT mo.saldo FROM movimientos AS mo WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo AND (identrada = (SELECT MAX(identrada) FROM movimientos mo WHERe mo.fecha BETWEEN '2020-02-09 00:00:00' AND '2021-11-23 00:00:00' )) ) AS saldo,
(SELECT m.cantidad FROM material AS m WHERE mo.codigo_material = m.codigo ) AS total,
mo.fecha from material as m 
inner join unidad_medida uni on  uni.idunidad_medida =  m.unidad 
inner join movimientos mo on mo.codigo_material= m.codigo 
where mo.fecha BETWEEN '2020-02-09 00:00:00' AND '2021-11-23 00:00:00'  
GROUP BY m.codigo ASC
```

Comment: ¿Esto soluciona tu problema? De ser así, edita la respuesta para explicar. Si no es la solución, borra esta respuesta y edita la pregunta para poner este nuevo código y decir qué es lo que falla.

Comment: ahi lo agregue bro, gracias